# Looping through an array of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift, ios8, for-in-loop

The code is as follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
                    var error: NSError?
                    let responseDictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as Dictionary
                    let venuesArray: AnyObject = (responseDictionary as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("response.venues")

                    for test: AnyObject in venuesArray {
                        println(test)
                    }
                });
```

The error I get is: `Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'`

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `venuesArray` the loop is expecting the array type not single object:

In your code : `let venuesArray: AnyObject =` // this is not array,

`let venuesArray: AnyObject[] =` // this could be the array of anyObject's

Try accordingly to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I changed it to Array<AnyObject> instead, but this would have worked too. Thanks

Comment: @Nilzone- This is very likely slower, so I'd advise against it as a best practice, since Array<AnyObject> is the full type now, and is inherently different from AnyObject[]